# a branch became a PRODUCT, what now? new repo?

Tags: git

I have a repo, and started to experiment (as usual) on a branch for the creation of a feature. This branch resulted on a success at such level that it's not a feature anymore but it became a project on it's own.

At this very moment I keep running both projects as branches cause I still share classes.

I would like though to have 2 repositories and to be able to share (cherry-pick) commit between them (on both directions).

My tree looks something like this:

```
----*------*--*--*-----*------------------- ... -------
     \----*------*--------*--- ... ------------
```

I'm tired of keeping this as a single project since there are some documents that I would prefer not to track but that I have to track just so that they change when I checkout the appropriate branch.

I was thinking about forking it to create a new repo, and then on each repo kill the other branch. But I don't know how this will affect the collaboration (merging or cherry-picking, or else) between the 2 repos.

Any suggestions please on what is the appropriate procedure for this kind of tasks?

Thank you guys in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your two projects share some code, the way to go is probably to extract the common functionality into a separate library. Chances are that you will have yet another project using the code and you would have to do this anyway - maybe the other project needs some older version or you would like to change the API and you don't want to adjust the other projects as well.

So, 2 project repositories, 1 library repository.

Comment: I like this approach, and it was they way I thought to follow at the beginning, but the code is to intrinsic right now as to take the shared Classes out as a base lib.

And thought that as a first step and while I create the generic API I could already separate the repo into 2 repos and continue sharing commits between them till the API is ready.

How would you separate the repos, from scratch with a git init and pasting the state of the FEATURE branch in it? or would you fork the original and rebase in this new one the FEATURE branch into master? or else...

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts - that's how I would do it:

1. Create two repositories, one per project.
2. Don't cherry-pick. Instead, create a new project - which could result in a new repository or could live in one of the existing - and put the shared stuff into that new project.